# Print array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I want to print an array of objects on my template but I'm getting some problems trying to do it. This is the json on which theres the array `historico`

```
{
      "id": 2,
      "tipo_negociacao": "Cobrança",
      "historico": [
        {
          "fl_usuario": "",
          "created_at": "",
          "updated_at": "",
          "created_by": null,
          "updated_by": null,
          "texto": "Proposta realizada valor de R$666666666"
        },
        {
          "texto": "Proposta no valor de R$:5762recusada"
        },
        {
          "texto": "Proposta realizada valor de R$6750"
        },
    }
```

So, as you can see, `historico`is an array of objects and what I want to do is to print all `texto` values on the screen. 
This is the part of the template where I try to print it:

```
<div *ngFor="let historico of disputa">
  <p> Negociação não iniciada </p>
  <p *ngFor="let historico of disputa.historico"> {{historico.texto}} </p>
</div>
```

Im using this to use data from `disputa`:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
  let id = params['id'];
  this.service
  .buscaPorId(id)
  .subscribe(disputa => {
    this.disputa = disputa;
  },
  erro => console.log(erro));
})
```

Im getting this error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a typo... `let historico of disputas` should be `disputa` that's the name of the array. Update: and be careful about the naming of your variables, the first variable in which you save disputas it's fine but I think the second one will cause conflict

Comment: thanks for the tip, I've updated the question since even without the typo I'm still having problems trying to print it

Comment: I would be money that what you are getting from the `buscaPorId(id)` call is not an array. If you do a `console.log(this.disputa));` after the service call, does show an array, or an object?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's it, It's returning me an object because its a parametrized route where I only receive the "disputa` with the same id as the route

Comment: That one gets me all the time. :)

Comment: Im kind of glad Im not the only one haha. So, do you have any idea of how can I access the array that is inside of this object and print it?

Comment: That second `*ngFor`, alone, should do that.

Comment: that's weird, on the console.log it shows me the array `historico` inside the `disputa` object but when I try to use it on ngFor or try to print it like: `disputa.historico` it returns me that "Cannot read property 'historico' of undefined"

Comment: Make sure that, in your HTML template, you check to see that the `disputa` variable is truthy before you try to access it. You can use `*ngIf` for that.

Comment: That's it, I forgot the *ngIf, thanks a lot for your help man. If you want to put these coments as answer just do it and I mark it as solution. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because of the outer `ngFor` you have:

```
<div *ngFor="let historico of disputa">
```

`disputa` is an Object, and cannot therefore be iterated.

Just remove that outer iteration and you are good to go, so your template should simply look like this:

```
<p *ngFor="let historico of disputa.historico"> {{historico.texto}} </p>
```

Here's a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tHd7xe9seFaYnERbJpuP?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p *ngFor="let historico of disputa.historico"> {{historico.texto}} </p>
```

is supposed to be

```
<p *ngFor="let data of historico.historico"> {{data.texto}} </p>
```

As `historico` variable in the first `ngFor` is already pointing to the current object in iteration.

```
// Or even better, change the name of the variable in the outermost loop
// so that you have the correct context in the inner loop.

<div *ngFor="let data of disputa">  <--- historico is already in context
  <p> Negociação não iniciada </p>
  <p *ngFor="let historico of data.historico"> {{historico.texto}} </p>
</div>
```

**Update**

There might be a possibility, that angular is not recognizing that the incoming data is array. Explicitly try to convert it to an array before piping it in.

```
<p *ngFor="let historico of convertToArray(data.historico)"> {{historico.texto}} </p>
```

In your component.

```
convertToArray(arrayObj) {
  return Array.from(arrayObj);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm getting the same error "Cannot find a differ..."

Comment: Sorry, what I was sending is an object, but I want to access the array that is inside of this object. do you have any idea how i can do this?

Comment: In the above case `disputa` is an array of objects, in which the first index ( object ) is assigned to data. Then when it comes to the 2nd loop, you want to access the `array` which is is `data.historico`. Instead of directly passing it to `ngFor` convert it to an array explicitly.

Comment: I tried what you answer, I'm not getting the error anymore, however it does'nt print anything

Comment: `disputa` is actually an object, what I want is to print the array `historico` that is inside  `disputa`